# TypeError: string indices must be integers in pandas_datareader

Tags: yahoo

I've asked Jupyter Labs the following:

import datetime as dt
end = dt.datetime.now()
start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)
start, end

stocklist = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL']
stocklist

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start, end)
df

And I'm continually getting back:

raceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16824\1247235532.py in 
----> 1 df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start, end)
2 df

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in get_data_yahoo(*args, **kwargs)
78
79 def get_data_yahoo(*args, **kwargs):
---> 80     return YahooDailyReader(*args, **kwargs).read()
81
82

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in read(self)
256             df = self._dl_mult_symbols(self.symbols.index)
257         else:
--> 258             df = self._dl_mult_symbols(self.symbols)
259         return df
260

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in _dl_mult_symbols(self, symbols)
266             for sym in sym_group:
267                 try:
--> 268                     stocks[sym] = self._read_one_data(self.url, self._get_params(sym))
269                     passed.append(sym)
270                 except (IOError, KeyError):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
151         try:
152             j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
--> 153             data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
154         except KeyError:
155             msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"

TypeError: string indices must be integers

What's going wrong?

Thanks.